# Black sun animation in iTunes. Does anyone know what it is?

Tags: itunes

I got this black sun animation inside my iTunes.

It was triggered by some shortcut, but I can't remember which one.

Does anyone know what it is?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

That is the `Visualizer`.  You can press Command + T (Ctrl + T on Windows) to start it.  Or it is available form the View Menu.

```
View --> Show Visualizer
```

Also in the View Menu you can change some of the settings for the way the `Visualizer` looks.

```
View --> Visualizer --> <More Options Here>
```